# Problem using setInnerFBML to put "fb:flv" tag for carousel

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs

I am using the following code for a video link in my page:

```
<a id="slide1" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/abcdef" title="aha">
    <img src=\"http://www.test.something.com/hwdvideos/thumbs/oopsie.jpg" 
         onclick=\"showvid('http://www.youtube.com/v/abcdef')"
    />
</a>
```

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
function showvid(var1)
{     
    document.getElementById('videoshowX').setInnerFBML("<fb:flv src='http://www.mediacollege.com/video-gallery/testclips/barsandtone.flv' width='400' height='300' title='my movie' color='#FFBB00' salign='r' img='http://www.example.com/test.jpg' scale='showall'/>");        
}
```

My problem is this:

I can get to set the inner FBML thingy. It doesnt do anything. However, any other text or link works just fine. Can anyone please enlighten me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass a string to setInnerFBML. You have to pass a fb:js-string OBJECT.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/js-string